# DJI Matrices 100 - Mission Planner “Heads-up Display (HUD)” does not display any values in the UI?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am having DJI Matrices 100 Quadcopter. I connected the  DJI Matrices 100 Quadcopter to  Mission planner (version 1.3.586) through UDP connection. 
But after I connected to Mission Planner, there is a pop-up windows shows that “Getting Params” mode.  The pop-up windows is always shows up without any progress forever. Looks Like it cannot be able to retrieve the parameters.
Only option I have is to cancel this process or let it run hours on end. After cancel the “Getting Params” pop-up windows, the Mission Planner “Heads-up Display (HUD)” does not display any values in the UI?

If I run the Simulation, still the HUB does not display any values.  Looks like it is related “Getting Params”  pop-up windows  issue?

Base on the log message, the  Mission planner sending  param request message  PARAM_REQUEST_READ(#20)   with  PARAM_REQUEST_LIST(#21) to DJI drone the mavlink protocol .  The DJI Drone needs to parameter  values  through PARAM_VALUE ( #22 ) to the Mission planner. But the DJI Drone does not reply with parameter  values . Then the Mission planner keep on sending the PARAM_REQUEST_READ(#20)    to the DJI Drone. That is reason the “Getting Params” pop-up windows is always shown in the  Mission planner.

Here is sample log message 
 [dji2mav] [TRACE] /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/onboard-sdk-ros/dji_sdk_dji2mav/include/dji_sdk_dji2mav/mavHandler.h, recvFromMng, 408: Totally 1 messages are received from Manager of index 0. Message id 20
[dji2mav] [TRACE] /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/onboard-sdk-ros/dji_sdk_dji2mav/include/dji_sdk_dji2mav/mavHandler.h, recvFromMng, 408: Totally 1 messages are received from Manager of index 0. Message id 20.
[dji2mav] [TRACE] /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/onboard-sdk-ros/dji_sdk_dji2mav/include/dji_sdk_dji2mav/mavHandler.h, sendEncodedMsgToMng, 319: ...succeed in sending encoded message with id 32 to Manager with index 0.
[dji2mav] [TRACE] /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/onboard-sdk-ros/dji_sdk_dji2mav/include/dji_sdk_dji2mav/mavHandler.h, sendEncodedMsgToMng, 319: ...succeed in sending encoded message with id 30 to Manager with index 0.
[dji2mav] [TRACE] /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/onboard-sdk-ros/dji_sdk_dji2mav/include/dji_sdk_dji2mav/mavHandler.h, sendEncodedMsgToMng, 319: ...succeed in sending encoded message with id 33 to Manager with index 0.
[dji2mav] [TRACE] /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/onboard-sdk-ros/dji_sdk_dji2mav/include/dji_sdk_dji2mav/mavHandler.h, recvFromMng, 408: Totally 1 messages are received from Manager of index 0. Message id 20.
[dji2mav] [TRACE] /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/onboard-sdk-ros/dji_sdk_dji2mav/include/dji_sdk_dji2mav/mavHandler.h, recvFromMng, 408: Totally 1 messages are received from Manager of index 0. Message id 20.
[dji2mav] [TRACE] /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/onboard-sdk-ros/dji_sdk_dji2mav/include/dji_sdk_dji2mav/mavHandler.h, recvFromMng, 408: Totally 1 messages are received from Manager of index 0. Message id 20.

1. What are the parameters need to send to MP?
2. Would helps to provide any example code ?